# Exporting to SVG in ArcMap. How to change or call svg clippath polygon attributes in CSS

Tags: arcgis-10.2, export, html, svg, css

Recently I exported a map document from the ESRI ArcMap 10.2.2 to SVG.

I would like to animate this map with css and javascript however the "clippath" polygons that arcmap creates makes it impossible to do so.  How would can I get the group "Puerto Rico" to highlight over mouseover.

This is a summary of the code:

```
<svg width="1008pt" height="612pt" viewBox="0 0 1008 612" enable-background="new 0 0 1008 612" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="Puerto_Rico_and_Virgin_Islands">
    <g id="state" class="test">
        <g id="Puerto_Rico">
            <clipPath id="SVG_CP_1">
                <path d= coordinates are put in here />
            </clipPath>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

```
<style type="text/css">
.test{
fill: grey;
stroke:#fff;
stroke-width:0.75;
stroke-opacity:1;
fill: orange;
}
#state:hover {
fill: red !important;
</style>
```

The real code:

visit jsfiddle for the entire code http://jsfiddle.net/jwitcoski/arv4g21f/3/

Using the wikipedia svg map that does not use clippath I was able to get everything to work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jwitcoski/y3yhgjjy/9/

Comment: I asked this question elsewhere on stackoverflow it was answered to the tune that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804799/how-to-change-or-call-svg-clippath-polygon-attributes-in-css/26858324#26858324